# Rails 4 Authentication using Devise with MongoMapper

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, mongomapper

I am working on a Rails 4 app and would like to use MongoMapper and Devise for authentication.  When I add devise to my Gemfile and bundle install it goes fine and I am able to `rails g devise:install`, and it picks up that I am using MongoMapper as my ORM.  When I try to `rails g mongo_mapper:config` it says it cannot find the generator.  Also I know that Devise supports Mongoid by default, but I like MongoMapper and would like to stick with that.  I downgraded to Rails 3.2.14 and it seems to work fine.  Any ideas on what I may be overlooking, or if Devise/MongoMapper support each other in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got also errors using the generators to create a model for the devise user.

This worked after using:

gem 'mongo_mapper', '>= 0.13.0.beta2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'mm-devise'

and then in the devise.rb:

require 'devise/orm/mongo_mapper'

After that I did not got into any erros.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem 'mongo_mapper'
gem 'devise'
gem 'mm-devise'
```

and also devise.rb should be

```
require 'mongo_mapper'
```